# How to print out only a specific number after decimal

Tags: java

I have been trying to print this out:

```
System.out.println("Year " + (2021 + j) + " you can buy " + ((int)(budget / total)) + " " +
        itemName + "s");
```

I'm supposed to only print out 2 decimals spaces and it's printing out many more than that. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this website about string format specifiers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/format-specifiers-in-java/). What you can do is use the `String.format` function, which returns a `String` and will let you specify how many decimal places you want to print out. In your case, that might look like:

```
String outputString = String.format("Year %d you can buy %.2f %ss", (2021 + j), (budget / total), itemName);
System.out.println(outputString);
```

The `%.2f` indicates that the corresponding argument should be printed as a floating point number and be rounded to two decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

#### General

If you are familiar with `printf` you can use it instead of `println`.

Otherwise there is a method called `format()` for Java Strings. A generic example to get the idea:

```java
double value = 2/3.0;
System.out.println("Original: " + value);
System.out.println(String.format("Formatted: %.2f", value));
```

---

#### Solution

For your situation the formatting would look something like this:

```java
System.out.println("Year " + (2021 + j) + " you can buy " + String.format("%.2f", budget/total) + " " + itemName + "s");
```

`%.Nf` keeps `N` decimals of a `double value`. That's why i removed the int typecast and assumed either budget or total variable will be type of double so the division returns a double value. If neither of those is double, int/int will return int value causing `format()` to throw and Exception because it expects double type value as second arguement since first argument had `f` in the way to format.

---

#### More

[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-string-format-method-with-examples/) you can find more detailed information for the number formatting topic.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31618258)

Comment: @ShockwaveNN thanks for the review. It must be improved now.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used java but you could do something like this

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float a = 30;
        float b = 6.5f;

        float answer1 = a / b;
        //Value is 4.6153846

        System.out.println(answer1);

        float answer2 = (float) (Math.floor((a / b) * 100)) / 100;
        //Multiplied 4.6153846 by 100 to 461.53846
        //Floored it to 461
        //Then divided it by 100
        System.out.println(answer2);

    }
}
```

Console:

```
4.6153846

4.61
```